# Complexity of Localization in Wireless Networks

Tags: cg.comp-geom

Let distinct points $1 ... n$ sit in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  We say points $i$ and $j$ are neighbors if $|i-j| < 3 \pmod{n-2}$, meaning each point is neighbors with points with indexes within $2$, wrapping around.

The problem is:

> For each pair of neighbors we are given their pairwise distances (and we know which distance corresponds to which points), and we want to reconstruct the
>   pairwise distances of all points.  My
>   questions is, what is the complexity
>   of this localization problem?

I don't know of a polynomial time algorithm.

This is motivated by problems in [localization in sensor networks](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/dkg6/papers/thesis.pdf), where agents, placed ad-hoc, can wirelessly communicate with their lexicographic neighbors, and we want to reconstruct their positions.

I don't know much about geometry / localization problems, so this might be easy or known.  The closest problem I know about is the [Turnpike problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/101#101), recently pointed out on this forum by @Suresh Venkat.

Comment: well-defined?
if two points are permitted to land on the same point in R^2, then you can make hinges.

Comment: sorry fixing...

Comment: Lev, it seems like tex is now enabled. can you try to edit your post to use latex and see if it works ?

Comment: you haven't clarified whether given a distance d I know which pair (i,j) made it. the difference is crucial

Comment: @suresh - I have clarified your question - we do know the corresponding distances.  also tex support is great! @Jukka - thanks I will check out your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I don't have a real answer, but this was too long for a comment, so posting it here anyway...)

I *suspect* that the problem is NP-hard, by reduction from the subset sum problem. A proof idea:

Reduction: if the $i$th element in the subset sum instance is $x_i$, then the distance between nodes $2i-1$ and $2i$ is $s$, distance between $2i-1$ and $2i+1$ is $x_i$, distance between $2i$ and $2i+2$ is also $x_i$, and distance between $2i$ and $2i+1$ is $\sqrt{s^2 + x_i^2}$.

Assume that the edges between $2i-1$ and $2i$ for all $i$ are vertical. Then the whole graph consists of a chain of rectangles with diagonals. However, you can "flip" each rectangle so that $2i+2$ is either on the left side of $2i$ or the right side of $2i$. And you need to find the right subset of flips so that the distance between the last node $n = 2k$ and the node $2$ is "correct" (and the distance between $2k-1$ and $1$ is correct and the distance between $2k-1$ and $2$ is correct).

So far so good, but our rectangles aren't really rigid; we could also flip along the diagonal. However, I think if we choose a nasty value $s$, then perhaps we could show that everything goes horribly wrong if we ever flip along a diagonal (e.g., the coordinates of $2k$ won't be rational)? This may require some tweaks in the values $x_i$, though.

Comment: interesting idea - thanks. a quick clarification question - what allows you to assume all 1-neighbor edges are vertical?

Comment: I'm only assuming that the edges 1-2, 3-4, ... are vertical. Of course you can choose the orientation of the edge 1-2 arbitrarily, and define that it is "vertical". Then there are only two possible configurations for the edge 3-4: either it is vertical *or* you have "flipped" (mirrored) along the edge 2-3. We'd like to avoid the second possibility which complicates the proof; see the part "so far so good..." for a possible idea of how to handle that.

Comment: I see - nice idea

Comment: Thm 4.1 (pg 50) of http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/dkg6/papers/thesis.pdf this thesis says that the square of any 2-connected graph has a unique localization.  Given you presented a global localization that is found by solving subset sum, we know there are no more answers (and do not have to worry about diagonal flips).  I think this finishes the proof!

Answer (score 6):

It is actually NP-hard. See the following paper for references.

Sriram V. Pemmaraju, Imran A. Pirwani: Good Quality Virtual Realization of Unit Ball Graphs. ESA 2007: 311-322

Comment: Do the references actually cover the special case mentioned in OP? That is, your graph topology is the square of a cycle?

Comment: You are so right. It covers only embeddings in to R^d.

Comment: Good reference though - thanks

Answer (score 4):

Drineas et al. wrote the paper [*Distance Matrix Reconstruction from Incomplete Distance Information for Sensor Network Localization*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.3194&rep=rep1&type=pdf). But what they achieve is probably not exactly what you ask for : they compute the whole distance map from an incomplete one, even in the presence of noise and node failures.