# Sum-of-square-roots-hard problems?

Tags: ds.algorithms, big-list, reductions, computing-over-reals

The [sum of square roots](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/4010#4010) problem asks, given two sequences $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$ of positive integers, whether the sum $\sum_i \sqrt{a_i}$ less than, equal to, or greater than the sum $\sum_i \sqrt{b_i}$.  The complexity status of this problem is open; see [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/4010#4010) for further details.  This problem arises naturally in computational geometry, especially in problems involving Euclidean shortest paths, and is a significant stumbling block in transferring algorithms for those problems from the real RAM to the standard integer RAM.

Call a problem Π *sum-of-square-roots-hard* (abbreviated Σ√-hard?) if there is a polynomial-time reduction from the sum of square roots problem to Π.  It is not hard to prove that the following problem is sum-of-square-roots-hard:

> **Shortest paths in 4d Euclidean geometric graphs**
>
> Instance: A graph $G=(V,E)$ whose vertices are points in $\mathbb{Z}^4$, with edges weighted by Euclidean distane; two vertices $s$ and $t$
>
> Output: The shortest path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$.

Of course this problem can be solved in polynomial-time on the real RAM using Dijkstra's algorithm, but each comparison in that algorithm requires solving a sum-of-square-roots problem.  The reduction uses the fact that any integer can be written as the sum of four perfect squares; the output of the reduction is actually a cycle on $2n+2$ vertices.

**What other problems are sum-of-square-roots-hard?**  I'm particularly interested in problems for which there is a polynomial-time solution on the real RAM.  See 
[my previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/complexity-of-computing-shortest-paths-in-the-plane-with-polygonal-obstacles) for one possibility.

As Robin suggests, boring answers are boring.  For any complexity class X that contains sum-of-square-roots (for example, PSPACE or EXPTIME), every X-hard problem is boringly  sum-of-square-roots-hard.

Comment: Thanks to Suresh and Peter for suggesting this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was discussed a bit in the following survey (starting slide 21): http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/kousha/games08_tutorial.pdf

which mentions Euclidean TSP, approximation of actual Nash equilibrium, and talks about the classes PosSLP and FIXP.

Comment: this is a fascinating connection.

Answer (score 22):

This should be a comment, as it is a mostly boring answer, but I don´t have enough reputation.

The sum of square roots problem is in $P^{PP^{PP^{PP}}}$ from [[ABKM98]](http://www-math.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/focs7.pdf), so any problem hard for this class has the required property. This is done by reducing the sum-of-square-roots problem to a problem called $PosSLP$, defined as deciding whether a straight-line problem represents a positive integer, so that problem is sum-of-square-roots hard.

[ABKM98]: On the Complexity of Numerical analysis, by Allender, Burgisser, Kjeldgaard-Pedersen and Miltersen.

Comment: There is also this improvement [http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~csaha/Sum_sqrroot.pdf] that puts the problem in ${CoRP}^{PP}$ and also proves that a restricted version of the problem needs a polynomial number of bits.

Comment: @Elias: Can you elaborate?  From a cursory look, [Kayal and Saha](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~csaha/Sum_sqrroot.pdf) seem to be discussing the “polynomial version” of the sum of square roots problem, which is related to but different from the usual sum of square roots problem.

Comment: @Abel: (1) Hi Abel, glad to see your post!  (2) For what it’s worth, [ABKM98] was actually presented at [CCC 2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/CCC.2006.30) and [published in 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/070697926).  (3) A boring answer should not be a comment but should be kept to yourself.  But I do not think that this is a boring answer. :)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: They solved completely the polynomial version of the problem. Based on this they prove that if $a_i$ are of special form, i.e. $a_i=\sum_i{b_ij}X^{d_i-j}$ where $X>(B+1)^{(nd)^{O(1)}}$, $B=max\{b_{ij}\}$ and  $d=max\{d_i\}$, then we need a polynomial number of bits to decide the problem.

Comment: @Elias: Thanks, but I know that.  How does it put the (unrestricted) integer version in coRP^PP?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I completely misunderstood your question. I am sorry for this. What Kayal and Saha prove is that DegSLP is in $CoRP^{PP}$. I should be more careful. Thank you for this.