# open problems on $NP$-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness

How can we find the list of open problems on $NP$-comlpete?

Comment: Do you mean a list of NP problems which are not known to be in P nor to be NP-complete? If so, this topic is an exact duplicate of [Problems Between P and NPC](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/79/873).

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous and vague, and without clarification cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. I am voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: You can try the NP-Completeness columns: http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/columns/. But I agree, this question is just too vague. Perhaps it can be rephrased as a reference request to a survey or something.

Comment: misagh, I closed this question because it is not clear what you are asking for and you have not replied to the comments after a month. We can reopen the question if you clarify it, just clarify it and then flag it for moderator attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also find some other problems in http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=category/theoretical_computer_science

Comment: Edit your previous answer instead adding new answers.

Comment: @Saeed: Although I upvoted your comment, after thinking about it again, I am not sure if I agree.  There are cases where posting two answers separately is acceptable.  Although the user 3008 could have edited the older answer, I do not know why he/she _should_ have done so or anyone could order him/her to do so.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito 伊藤剛志, yes may be if I said it's better to ... was better (but is not normal in QA sites), but if anyone wants to show his/her force to create new answer,I think he/she will downvote this answer. In this case I think user 3008 can edit answer and add too many item, I think user 3008 didn't see edit button.

Answer (score -2):

you can find some open Np-complete problem at the end of "computer and intractability" (Garey & Johnson)

Comment: -1: That is an old list.