# Testing Isomorphism of projective planes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-isomorphism

[Miller showed](https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=RjB40FbSDo4C&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=isomorphism+planes+designs+babai&source=bl&ots=h_4kwQ6zXo&sig=mu4bhEvIBMiTRgQDvoksG1qmxbY&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=isomorphism%20planes%20designs%20babai&f=false) that isomorphism testing of projective planes can be done in $v^{O(\log \log v)}$. I would like to know whether Babai's techniques that led to the quasipolynomial time algorithm for GI would colapse isomorphism testing for projective planes to polynomial time.

> Is Miller's algorithm still the best known upper-bound? What other natural *hard* problems can be solved in $n^{O(\log \log n)}$ time?

Here, *hard* means the problem has no known polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239382

Comment: Babai and Luks extended Miller's result to show that isomorphism testing for symmetric designs can be done in $n^{O(\log \log n)}$. (Theorem 3.3) 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808729761

Comment: Relatively recent paper by Huber suggests that Miller's algorithm is the best known algorithm (until 2010): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316510001044