# GI-hard graph problem not known to be $NP$-complete

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, np-intermediate

Graph Isomorphism ($GI$) is good candidate for $NP$-intermediate problem. $NP$-intermediate problems exist unless $P=NP$. I'm looking for natural problem that is hard for $GI$ under Karp reduction (A graph problem $X$ such that $GI <_p^m X$).

> Is there a natural $GI$-hard graph problem that is neither $GI$-equivalent nor known to be $NP$-complete?

Comment: GI-equivalent under Karp reduction.

Comment: candidates: [problems between P and NPC](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/)

Comment: It seems possible to construct an infinite hierarchy of such problems, by blending in "just enough of" Clique into GI, in a variant of Ladner's delayed diagonalization.  See also the similar construction suggested by Bodirsky/Chen/Grohe/Thurley/Weyer.

Comment: By the way, you might change the title to "GI-hard graph problem not known to be NP-complete." My first thought when I saw the current title was "Ring Isomorphism!" but the answer you found is (I think) significantly more interesting.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Thanks for your feedback. What do you suggest? Notice that I'm interested in graph problems.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: I already made the suggestion in my previous comment (though I admit it was easy to miss). Just add the word graph to the title: "GI-hard *graph* problems not known..."

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshuaGrochow. I edited the title as you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After extensive search, I found the Legitimate Vertex Deck problem (LVD) which is related to the famous [Graph Reconstruction conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture). A deck of graph $G(V, E)$ is a multi-set of graphs $F = \{G_1,G_2, . . . , G_n\}$ such that $G_i$ is isomorphic to $G−v_i$ ($G-v$ is a graph obtained from $G$ by removing $v$ and its incident edges). ($|V|=n$)

The k-LEGITIMATE VERTEX-SUBDECK problem, given multi-set of graphs $F= \{G_1,G_2, . . . , G_k\}$, Decide whether there is a graph $G$ such that $F$ is a subset of its vertex-deck (**k-LVD** =$ \{[G_1, . . . , G_k]|(∃G)[[G_1, . . . , G_k] ⊆ vertex-deck(G)]\}$) 
where $k \ge 3$

**k-LVD** problem is $GI$-hard and is not known to be $GI$-equivalent. It is open problem whether **k-LVD** is $NP$-complete (for $k \ge 3$). See the open problems section of [Complexity results in graph reconstruction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06002228).

Also, the paper suggests the existence of a problem of intermediate complexity between $GI$ and **k-LVD**. The problem is **LVD**= **n-LVD** where all $n$ candidate cards are given (Input for **LVD** is $F= \{G_1,G_2, . . . , G_n \})$.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler problem could be WEIGHTED_HYPERGRAPH_ISOMORPHISM. You are given two hypergraphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ on $n$ vertices with weighted hyper-edges, decide if there is a vertex permutation $pi$ turning $G_1$ into $G_2$.

Comment: This is GI-complete.