# "Any" Subset Sum. Is it hard?

Tags: subset-sum

Here is a variant of the classic partition problem: Given a list of integers can it be partitioned into $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$, with $S_1$ and $S_2$ nonempty, so the sum of elements in $S_1$ equals the sum of elements in $S_2$?

Is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: [This answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3993/6973) is somewhat related. $\;$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is known to be NP-complete: On the equal-subset-sum problem, Woeginger and Yu, IPL'92.

Comment: I think that paper proves that PARTITION is NP-complete. There's a straightforward reduction to the OP's problem, but it's not the same because of the three sets and non-emptiness constraints.

Comment: @Huck: Did you read [the abstract](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909290226L) of the paper? That paper appears to be the ***exact*** same problem as the OP is asking. Let $S_3 = S - (S_1 \cup S_2)$.

Comment: @HuckBennett, what is the straightforward reduction?

Comment: @Peter, Radu: You're right. Unfortunately I read both the OP's post and the abstract carelessly.

Comment: Also, for the sake of historical accuracy, PARTITION was known to be $\mathbb{NP}$-complete at least since Karp's list of 21 problems, as a special (but still hard to solve) case of KNAPSACK. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp's_21_NP-complete_problems) and figure 1, page 96, in the original [paper](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~sgk/teaching/grad/handouts/karp.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. Using dynamic programming, we can solve this problem in pseudo-polynomial time $O(nN)$, where $n$ is the number of integers in the list and $N$ is the sum of all integers in the list, as follows. For $m \leq n$, $|M| \leq N$, and $c \in \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$, let $T(m, M, c)$ tell whether it is possible to partition the first $m$ integers into sets $S_1, S_2, S_3$, so that $(\sum S_2) - (\sum S_1) = M$, and $S_i$ is nonempty for every $i \in c$. Say the integers are $x_1, \dots, x_n$. We have the recurrence
$$ T(m, M, c) = T(m - 1, M, c) \vee T(m - 1, M + x_m, c \setminus \{1\}) \vee T(m - 1, M - x_m, c \setminus \{2\}). $$
(We can choose to put $x_m$ in $S_3$, or in $S_1$, or in $S_2$.) From here, the straightforward DP algorithm gives us every value of $T(m, M, c)$ in time $O(nN)$; the answer to the problem is $T(n, 0, \{1, 2\})$.