# Algorithm for finding a 3-cycle cover

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, implementation

**Given:** An undirected, unweighted graph

**Looking for:** A disjoint vertex cycle cover where every cycle has at least 3 edges

Is there any algorithm that solves this problem, possibly with some heuristics? Can the bipartite representation of the graph used for finding perfect matching be leveraged here?

Comment: I think that you are mixing up results for the undirected and for the directed version of the problem.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, could you explain to us why you think that your problem is NP-hard?

Comment: Because I have not seen an actual algorithm that can solve this problem in polynomial time.

Comment: What I am doing right now is using the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm to obtain a maximum matching on the bipartite representation of the original graph. This maximum matching on the bipartite graph is a cycle cover when mapped to the original graph, but it may contain paths. What I didn't fully understand is if this method gives any guarantee reagrding cycle lengths.

Answer (score 22):

The *cycle cover* problem (CC) is the problem of finding a spanning set of cycles in a given directed or undirected input graph. 
If all the cycles in the cover must consist of at least $k$ edges/arcs, the resulting restriction of the problem is denoted $k$-UCC (in undirected graphs) and $k$-DCC (in directed graphs).

The complexity of the directed version is fully understood:

- Markus Bläser and Bodo Siebert ("Computing Cycle Covers without Short Cycles", in Proceedings of ESA 2001, LNCS 2161, pp 368--379) have proved that $k$-DCC is **NP-complete** for any fixed $k\ge3$.

The complexity landscape of the undirected version is more diverse, and there are some open questions:

- $3$-UCC is **polynomially solvable**. This is a folklore result that follows from a reduction of Tutte ("A short proof of the factor theorem for finite graphs", Canadian Journal of Mathematics 6, pp 347–352, 1954) to the classical unrestricted matching problem.
- David Hartvigsen (in his PhD thesis "An Extension of Matching Theory", Carnegie-Mellon University, 1984) has shown that $4$-UCC is **polynomially solvable**.
- The complexity status of $5$-UCC is **open**. David Hartvigsen has some positive results on special cases of this problem ("The square-free 2-factor problem in bipartite graphs", in Proceedings of IPCO 1999, LNCS 1610, pp 234–241).
- Papadimitriou has proved that $k$-UCC is **NP-complete** for any fixed $k\ge6$. His proof is sketched in the 1980 paper "A matching problem with side conditions" by Gerard Cornuejols and Bill Pulleyblank (Discrete Mathematics 29, pp 135--159).

Comment: Nice summary of problem's complexity.

Comment: BTW, Do you know analogous results for cubic graphs (undirected and directed)?

Comment: Very interesting.  5-UCC should be added to the [list of problems between P and NPC](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc).