# Finding a minimal addition chain for a given number

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete

An addition chain for computing a positive integer $n$ is a sequence of natural numbers starting with $1$ and ending with $n$, such that each number in the sequence is the sum of two previous numbers.

Question: Is this problem NP-complete?

Wiki says the following about [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0210047):

*A number of other papers state that finding a shortest addition chain for a single number is NP-complete, citing this paper, but it does not claim or prove such a result.*

(In fact, in this paper were proved NP-completeness the following generalization: to find a chain that simultaneously forms each of a sequence of values).

Should we add Addition chain problem to [the list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc)?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not known to be NP-complete. Some references assume erroneously NP-completness. Furthermore, technically, minimum addition chain  is search problem. I guess you are asking for NP-hardness proof.