# Intermediate Problems between FP and #P

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, counting-complexity, conditional-results

Do there exist intermediate problems (in the sense of Ladner's Theorem) for FP vs. #P? I assume that something is known, because I read some papers concerned with FP/#P dichotomies. However, I couldn't find a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Use Schöning's theorem:

> Let $A_1$, $A_2$ be recursive sets and $C_1$, $C_2$ be classes of recursive sets with the following properties:
>
> 1. $A_1 \notin C_1$, $A_2 \notin C_2$
> 2. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are recursively presentable,
> 3. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed under finite variations.
>
> Then there exists a recursive set $A$ such that:
>
> 1. $A \notin C_1$, $A \notin C_2$,
> 2. if $A_1 \in \mathsf{P}$ and $A_2\notin \{ \emptyset, \Sigma^* \}$, then $A \leq^{\mathsf{P}}_m A_2$.

For the purposes of counting dichotomy theorems, the two relevant classes of decision problems are $\text{P}$ and $\text{P}^{\#\text{P}}$.

Comment: [Schöning theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2882%2990114-1): [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/8046/) and [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/7640).

Comment: @Kaveh Oh, great.  Thanks Kaveh.  I incorporated your linked info into my answer.

Comment: Are oracle classes obviously c.e.?
 Schöning's result relies on both the classes being c.e.

Comment: @András, it requires the languages in the classes to be decidable and in addition we should be able to computably enumerate the languages inside them. I guess you are concerned with the second one. If two classes are computably presentable then their oracle class is also: just enumerate their product.