# Example of #P-intermediate problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity

## [The previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17824/17082)

Do there exist intermediate problems (in the sense of Ladner's Theorem) for FP vs. #P? I assume that something is known, because I read some papers concerned with FP/#P dichotomies. However, I couldn't find a reference.

## [An Answer to the previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17827/17082)

Use Schöning's theorem:

> Let $A_1$, $A_2$ be recursive sets and $C_1$, $C_2$ be classes of recursive sets with the following properties:
>
> 1. $A_1 \notin C_1$, $A_2 \notin C_2$
> 2. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are recursively presentable,
> 3. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed under finite variations.
>
> Then there exists a recursive set $A$ such that:
>
> 1. $A \notin C_1$, $A \notin C_2$,
> 2. if $A_1 \in \mathsf{P}$ and $A_2\notin \{ \emptyset, \Sigma^* \}$, then $A \leq^{\mathsf{P}}_m A_2$.

For the purposes of counting dichotomy theorems, the two relevant classes of decision problems are $\text{P}$ and $\text{P}^{\#\text{P}}$.

## My question

> Is there a concrete example of #P intermediate problem under some plausible assumption?
>   More specifically, is there an *explicit* function $F$ satisfying the following conditions?
>   $F\notin \mathsf{FP}$ and $F$ is *not*  $\# \mathsf{P}$-complete.

Comment: For P vs. $\mathrm{P^{\#P}}$, just take SAT, or any other problem in the polynomial hierarchy assumed not to be in P.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming $\mathsf{PH}$ does not collapse and that Graph Isomorphism is not in $\mathsf{P}$, then $\# GI$ (the counting version of graph isomorphism) satisfies your conditions. This is because $\# GI \equiv_m^p GI$.

Comment: I have a simple clarification. If $P=NP$ then is $\#GI$ is $\#P$-complete?

Comment: Unknown. If that were true, then we would have P=NP implies $FP = \# P$ (since $\# GI$ is equivalent to GI), but the latter implication is not known.